# Errors When Input are Letters & Symbols Instead Of Int That Is Requested

Tags: java

I am a student writing this program that is suppose to convert Tsubo to (ft²). I have had no issues with this source code, but I am concerned that I may loose points for an issue I have encountered while testing. The issue is that when asked to enter a integer, if I enter a letter or symbol then I get an error that brings the program to a complete stop. This is my method:

```
public static void tsubo(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tsubo;
    double product;
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter Tsubo to convert to (ft²): ");
    tsubo = keyboard.nextInt();
    product = tsubo * 35.58;
    System.out.println("Your conversion equals\n" + product + "(ft²)" + "\n");
}
```

What can I do to stop this error from occurring when a letter or symbol is entered when asked for an integer?

Answer (score 0):

From running the code you wrote, calling `tsubo = keyboard.nextInt();` throws a `java.util.InputMismatchException` when called with a letter or symbol.

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html):

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

In your case, all you have to do is wrap the line in a try-catch block and end the program so it doesn't try to calculate anything:

```
try {
    tsubo = keyboard.nextInt();
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please input a number, not a letter or symbol.");
    return;
}
```

which, upon inputting a symbol or letter, will print:

```
Please input a number, not a letter or symbol.
```

Answer (score -1):

the int variable tsubo has not been initialized. Local variables don't get automatically initializes in Java.

Comment: The variable gets initilaized before using it. This is ok (and recommended).